# Calculate time between events in a day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset:

```
date                  event      next_event            duration_Minutes
2021-09-09 22:30:00    1         2021-09-09 23:00:00        30
2021-09-09 23:00:00    2         2021-09-09 23:10:00        10
2021-09-09 23:10:00    1         2021-09-09 23:50:00        40
2021-09-09 23:50:00    4         2021-09-10 00:50:00        60
2021-09-10 00:50:00    4         2021-09-12 00:50:00        2880
```

The main problem is that I would like to split the multi-day events into separate events in the following way. I would like to have the event duration from `2021-09-09 23:50:00`  until `2021-09-10 00: 00: 00` and then the duration from `2021-09-10 00: 00: 00` to `2021-09-10 00:50:00`, and so on. This would be useful because after, I would need to group the events by day and calculate the duration of the each event by day, so I would like to fix these situation in which there is the day change between events.
I would like to obtain something like this:

```
date                  event      next_event            duration_Minutes
2021-09-09 22:30:00    1         2021-09-09 23:00:00        30
2021-09-09 23:00:00    2         2021-09-09 23:10:00        10
2021-09-09 23:10:00    1         2021-09-09 23:50:00        40
2021-09-09 23:50:00    4         2021-09-10 00:00:00        10
2021-09-09 00:00:00    4         2021-09-10 00:50:00        50
2021-09-10 00:50:00    4         2021-09-11 00:00:00        1390
2021-09-11 00:00:00    4         2021-09-12 00:00:00        1440
2021-09-12 00:00:00    4         2021-09-12 00:50:00        50
```

It should be able to handle situations in which we don't have an event for an entire day or more like in the example.

My current solution for now is:

```
first_record_hour_ts = df.index.floor('H')[0]
last_record_hour_ts = df.index.floor('H')[-1]

# Create a series from the first to the last date containing Nan
df_to_join = pd.Series(np.nan, index=pd.date_range(first_record_hour_ts, last_record_hour_ts, freq='H'))
df_to_join = pd.DataFrame(df_to_join)
# Concatenate with current status dataframe
df = pd.concat([df, df_to_join[~df_to_join.index.isin(df.index)]]).sort_index()
# Forward fill the nana
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

df['next_event'] = df.index.shift(-1)
# Calculate the delta between the 2 status
df['duration'] = df['next_event'] - df.index
# Convert into minutes
df['duration_Minutes'] = df['duration_Minutes'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds() // 60)
```

This doesn't solve exactly the problem, but I think it may solve my goal which being able to group by event and by day at the end.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: So right now my solution is the following: I take only the date and event columns. I create a pandas series within the data range by hours .I join  so that I have all the possible hours for each day together with the previous timestamps. Then I forward fill the 'NaN' values in the event column with the previous value. I then calculate the next event and the duration. In this way I think I am able to solve the problem of the events in multiple day, even if I have more lines, because at the end my goal is to group the data by day, so I think it should work like this.

Comment: I think it would be useful if we could see your actual code -- you can edit your question to add it there. Thinking out loud, I think that I would want to separate the cases where the date-next_event gap does or doesn't cross over midnight. Those that cross over midnight have to be handled separately since they're split, potentially across multiple days.

Comment: Ok I added the code I have written right now

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on a solution right now, I'll let you know how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the code below looks a bit long -- and there's certainly a better/more efficient/shorter way of doing this. But I think it's pretty reasonably simple to follow along.

`split_datetime_span_by_day` below takes two dates: `start_date` and `end_date`. In your case, it would be `date` and `next_event` from your source data.

The function then checks whether that time period (start -> end) spans over midnight. If it doesn't, it returns the start date, the end date, and the time period in seconds. If it does span over midnight, it creates a new segment (start -> midnight), and then calls itself again (i.e. recurses), and the process continues until the time period does not span over midnight.

Just a note: the returned segment list is made up of tuples of (start, end, nmb_seconds). I'm returning the number of seconds, not the number of minutes as in your question, because I didn't know how you wanted to round the seconds (up, down, etc.). That's left as an exercise for the reader :-)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def split_datetime_span_by_day(start_date, end_date, split_segments=None):
  assert start_date < end_date # sanity check

  # when is the next midnight after start_date?
  # adapted from https://ispycode.com/Blog/python/2016-07/Get-Midnight-Today
  start_next_midnight = datetime.combine(start_date, datetime.min.time()) + timedelta(days=1)

  if split_segments is None:
    split_segments = []

  if end_date < start_next_midnight:
    # end date is before next midnight, no split necessary
    return split_segments + [(
      start_date,
      end_date,
      (end_date - start_date).total_seconds()
    )]

  # otherwise, split at next midnight...
  split_segments += [(
    start_date,
    start_next_midnight,
    (start_next_midnight - start_date).total_seconds()
  )]

  if (end_date - start_next_midnight).total_seconds() > 0:  
    # ...and recurse to get next segment
    return split_datetime_span_by_day(
      start_date=start_next_midnight,
      end_date=end_date,
      split_segments=split_segments
    )
  else:
    # case where start_next_midnight == end_date i.e. end_date is midnight
    # don't split & create a 0 second segment
    return split_segments

# test case: 
start_date = datetime.strptime('2021-09-12 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end_date = datetime.strptime('2021-09-14 01:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(split_datetime_span_by_day(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date))

# returned values:
# [
#   (datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 0, 0), 86400.0),
#   (datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 13, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 14, 0, 0), 86400.0),
#   (datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 14, 1, 0), 3600.0)
# ]
```

Comment: Thanks, at the end I was also able to make my solution works for my end-goal that was the grouping by day and event.